# How to get a js variable value and give it to C# variable in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Noob needs help)
Here I have an AJAX script for partial view refreshing, but I need to give the `link` value to `Model.Path` and I don't know how to do it.

```
<script>
        $('.createdb a item').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            var link = $(this).text();
            $('.createdb').load(@Html.Partial("CreateDB")); 
        });
</script>
```

Just `@Model.Path += link` equals syntax error

Comment: what is Model.Path? a back-end method/class/what? need more details...

Comment: `Model.Path` is a public string property of the model used in this view

Comment: if you are trying to dynamically load a partial use an ajax call.  see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340245/how-to-pass-id-in-jquery/23343088#23343088

Comment: I do. On the main page I render a partial view with a number of buttons within it. I need to refresh only partial view on clicking any button. Will it fit for this?