# Helping about Asp.Net MVC ajax request

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I use Asp.net MVC. I have a page. When I click menu link on the page, I want to load a partialview to that page. I wrote a code like below.

```
 $("a.submit").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var UnitId = id.split("_")[1];
        var categoryId = $("#hdnCategory").val();

        $.blockUI({
            css: { backgroundColor: 'transparent', color: '#fff', border: 'none' },
            message: '<h1><img src="../Content/images/loading.gif" style="width:300px;height:300px" /></h1>'

        });


        $.ajax({
            url: '@rootPath/KaliteDokumanYonetimi/GetDocumentsByUnit',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            data: '{unitId:'+UnitId+'}',
            success: function (result) {
              //  alert("success");
                $.unblockUI();
            },
            error: function () {
                $.unblockUI();
                alert("sorun oluştu");
            }
        });
    });
```

---

```
    //this is also my controller action code piece.
    public JsonResult GetDocumentsByUnit(string unitId)
    {
        return Json(true,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

my codes are like above. My problem is that, I can not take unitI value from Action Method. It comes as null. In javascript side, I control this value that it comes correct. How can I take unitId value from Action method. 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340245/how-to-pass-id-in-jquery/23343088#23343088

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the suggested question... He isn't doing anything after the ajax call, and stated that his problem is that `unitId` is `null` in the action method.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is invalid. Don't try to build json strings via concatenation. Create a javascript object and pass it to `JSON.stringify()`:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ unitId : UnitId }),
```

You should also be doing a `POST` if you want to send json.... or append the id to the end of the url and make sure your route is set up properly.