# Rendering partial view of one model type into view of another model type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model, partial-views

New to MVC and I've not been able to understand answers to similar questions asked, so apologies if this is a repeat for people.

I have a details view using a character model:

```
@model Attacker.Models.Character

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Character</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Str)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Str)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Con)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Con)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Dex)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Dex)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Int)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Int)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Wis)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Wis)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cha)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Cha)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BaseAttack)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BaseAttack)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
   @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Weapons.cshtml")
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.CharacterID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

My Partial view at the end is essentially another details view but from a weapon model. My aim is to show a character and the weapons he owns on one view but I'm getting an error due to the conflicting model types.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I like to load partials like this through an ajax call.  see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340245/how-to-pass-id-in-jquery/23343088#23343088 for an example of that method

Comment: I unfortunately know even less Ajax than I do MVC =( Been trying to make sense of your example but it's escaping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from using Editor/Display templates, you can do it in two different ways:

1. include in your Attacker.Models.Character a list of model for weapons, and render them in a loop like this:

   `@foreach(weaponModel in Model.Weapons)
    {
       Html.RenderPartial("", weapon);
    }`
2. create an action to display a weapon by id (or whatever key you want to use). Include the weapon keys in your model, and render the action for each weapon (this example assumes that `ShowWeapon` is an action in the same controller, but you can, of course, use another controller by specifying it):

   `@foreach(weaponId in Model.WeaponIds)
    {
       Html.RenderAction("ShowWeapon", new {id = weaponId});
    }`

Using editor or display templates makes things easier, but is less flexible. It depends on what you need to achieve, or what you have already available.

**Edit: about "flexibility"**

To be more precise, an Editor or Display template is similar to a render partial, with the differece that the view template is automatically selected based upon the model type.

For example, if you define a type like 'Duration' which includes hours and minutes properties, you can create

- an Editor template to show it as "hh:mm"
- a Display template, that allows to input the value as "hh:mm" in a textbox.

This is great because, whenever you want to edit this kind of value you can rely in  `Html.EditorFor` or `Html.DisplayFor`, to get this template, without any extra work. And this is really useful because you can have a model with several `Duration` properties, and they'll get "automagically" bound in the correct way.

However, if you have a more complex model, with many properties inside it, it's quite probable that you want to show them in different ways. For example,

- depending on the permissions of the user logged in or on some business logic, Besides it can be neccesary to show an editor with some read only controls, or display only part of the values
- depending on the place where you are displaying it (in a full page, inside a jQuery UI dialog, as a detail in another page...) you may need different layouts.

Obviously, in this cases an editor / display template will be to rigid.

Definitely, if you will always show or edit a model exactly in the same way, use editor/display templates. If not, `RenderPartial` or `RenderAction` will give the required flexibility.

(NOTE: it's possible to customize the Display and Editor templates passing extra data to them, but this is much harder to implement that a normal view / action).

Comment: Why would you say templates are less flexible?  They're extremely flexible, and allow rendering based on type.. Try getting partials to automatically select the correct partial to render based on type.

Comment: Umm.. you do realize that EditorTemplates have an "extra data" field to pass to them....

Comment: Yes, of course. But I think that taking that path can be dangerous. You start by passing some basic extra data to do an small customizitaion to your editor or display template, and, when you want to realize, you're passing a lot of extra data and making two much things in your display or editor template. I.e. yor view is taking too much responsibilities, that should keep in the controller. That's why I prefer to restrict its use to simple domain types used along the whole application. For these, I use editor & display templates, and custom binders and html helpers.

Comment: To enrich this helpers and templates, I usually pass enums with significant names. But not many more that that. I feel that passing too much extra parameters is moving too much responsibilty to the view (presentation layer). That's why I think that a view that does too much things shouldn't be implemented as a template, but as another different view or even as a controller action, to make the diference more clear. Yes, it's a personal taste, but I think the responsibilities are clearer in this way.

Comment: We're comparing Templates to Partials... I don't understand how your answer can possibly relate to that comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, don't use Partials for this.  Use Editor or Display Templates instead.  I don't have the time to write a full response right now, others are free to if they want... These links should help for now.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx
http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/672591/Exploring-Display-and-Editor-Templates-in-ASP-NET